# mapStateToProps error if own props are not returned with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I have an example connected component here:

```js
import React, {FC, ReactElement} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

interface RootState {}

interface MyComponentProps {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const MyComponent: FC<MyComponentProps> = ({name, age}): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <div/>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state:RootState , ownProps: MyComponentProps) => {
  if (!("name" in ownProps)) {
    return {
      name: "foo"
    }
  }
  return {}
}

export const ConnectedMyComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

However, I get the following TypeScript error on passing the `MyComponent` to the connector.

```
Argument of type 'FC<MyComponentProps>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<({ name: string; } | { name?: undefined; }) & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, MyComponentProps>>'.
  Type 'FunctionComponent<MyComponentProps>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Matching<({ name: string; } | { name?: undefined; }) & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, MyComponentProps>>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'PropsWithChildren<Matching<({ name: string; } | { name?: undefined; }) & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, MyComponentProps>>' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithChildren<MyComponentProps>'.
        Type 'PropsWithChildren<Matching<({ name: string; } | { name?: undefined; }) & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, MyComponentProps>>' is not assignable to type 'MyComponentProps'.
          Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
            Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
              Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
```

I can fix this by returning `return {...ownProps}` when the if statement isn't true, but the [Redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#ownprops-optional) say that you shouldn't need to return the ownProps unless you are changing them, so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the fact that `mapStateToProps` will return a `name` if it is missing in `ownProps` is not encoded in its type signature, so from the point of view of `connect`, `name` could be undefined, even though this won't actually happen. I don't think there's a straightforward way to fix this in the types, so I would just pass the name from `ownProps` if it is not `undefined`. (You can also return the entire `ownProps`, but only the `name` property is necessary.)

```
const mapStateToProps = (state:RootState, ownProps: MyComponentProps) => ({
  name: ownProps.name !== 'undefined' ? ownProps.name : 'foo'
})
```

or, rewritten with nullish coalescing:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state:RootState, ownProps: MyComponentProps) => ({
  name: ownProps.name ?? 'foo'
})
```

Note that `ownProps.name !== 'undefined'` is slightly safer than `'name' in ownProps`, as declaring a prop as optional won't reject passing it with value `undefined` (e.g. `<Comp name={undefined} />`), in which case `'name' in ownProps` would be true.

**Update:**

As Linda Paiste noticed, the typings are a bit off. In the type of `ownProps` the `name` should be optional. You can declare a separarate type `OwnProps` (i.e. the props on the connected component):

```
interface OwnProps {
  name?: string;
  age: number;
}
```

and use

```
const mapStateToProps = (state:RootState, ownProps: OwnProps) => ({
  name: ownProps.name ?? 'foo'
})
```

Comment: There is some strange behavior here but OP's case doesn't make any sense because the `interface MyComponentProps` requires that `name` must **always** be in `ownProps`.

Comment: Ah yes, `ownProps` should be typed with an optional name, let me add that. It does not affect the solution though.